# Zend framerwork DB DDL update

Tags: php, zend-framework, ddl

I am new to zend and i want to use the DB module for an application.

I have this code

```
$DB = new Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter(array(
    'driver' => 'Mysqli',
    'database' => 'database',
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => 'pass'
));
use Zend\Db\Sql\Ddl;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Ddl\Column;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Ddl\Constraint;
$table = new Ddl\CreateTable('table');
$table->setTable('table');
$table->addColumn(new Column\Integer('id',false,NULL,array('autoincrement'=>true)));
$table->addColumn(new Column\Varchar('name', 255));
$table->addConstraint(new Constraint\PrimaryKey('id'));
```

Table is not created, there is an update function? i can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created **DDL statement object** and **Adapter**, but you haven't executed it. You will need 1 more object for execution and that's **SQL** instance. In your case it could look like this:

```
use Zend\Db\Sql\Sql;

// your code

$sql = new Sql($DB);

$DB->query(
    $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($table),
    $DB::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE
);
```

More at [Zend Framework's docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.db.sql.ddl.html#executing-ddl-statements)