# EDIT: Class Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter not found

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

I have a simple `form` which after submitting redirects to `processAction` inside `AuthController` and in this `action` I want to create a simple `table` **bar**.

**EDITED:**

Referring to [Zend framerwork DB DDL update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955562/zend-framerwork-db-ddl-update), I made a little modification in below code

**AuthController.php**

```
<?php

namespace Blog\Controller;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Zend\Debug\Debug;
use Blog\Form\LoginForm;
use Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Sql;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Ddl;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Ddl\Column;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Insert;
use Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable as DbTableAuthAdapter;

class AuthController extends AbstractActionController
{    
    protected $adapter;
    public function getAdapter()
    {
        if (!$this->adapter) {
            $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
            $this->adapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
        }
        return $this->adapter;
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        return new ViewModel();
    }

    public function processAction()
    {

       $DB = new \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter(array(
        'driver' => 'Pdo',
        'database' => 'blog',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => 'mysql'
       ));


        $this->adapter = $this->getAdapter();
        $sql = new Sql($this->adapter);
        $table = new Ddl\CreateTable('bar');
        $table->addColumn(new Column\Integer('id'));
        $table->addColumn(new Column\Varchar('name', 255));
        $table->setTable('bar'); 

        $results = $this->adapter->query($sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($table),  $this->adapter ::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
        return new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

**global.php:**

```
return array(
'db' => array(
    'driver'         => 'Pdo',
    'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=blog;host=localhost',
    'driver_options' => array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
    ),
),
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'
        => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
     ),
  ),
);
```

**Module.php**

```
  <?php
  namespace Blog;

  use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface;
  use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;

 class Module implements  AutoloaderProviderInterface,ConfigProviderInterface
  {

  public function getAutoloaderConfig()
  {
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
            ),
        ),
    );
}


public function getConfig()
{
    return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
}

public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' =>array( 
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => function ($sm) {
                 $config = $sm->get('Config');
                 return new \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter($config['db']);

         }
       )
    );
  }
}
```

**Problem:**(Updated)

`table` **bar** is not created and shows error like

> Fatal error: Class 'Blog\Controller\Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' not found
>   in /var/www/zend2/module/Blog/src/Blog/Controller/AuthController.php
>   on line 110

if I print

```
echo $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($table);
```

The query prints like this

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `bar` ( `id` INTEGER NOT NULL, `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL )
> ```

but table was not there.

**Error** occurs in below line of code as it is not able to identify `adapter` :

```
 $results = $this->adapter->query($sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($table),  $this->adapter ::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
```

But works in this way:

```
$results = $this->adapter->query($sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($table),  $DB ::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
```

I am using Zend `2.4`

Comment: are you sure that DB user has rights to `CREATE` an objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For beginners in `ZF2` ,the `query execute` won't work if you don't instantiate class `Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter` correctly.

I corrected like

```
 $DB = new \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter(array(
    'driver' => 'Pdo',
    'database' => 'blog',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'mysql'
   ));
```

Also below line of **code** :

```
$results = $this->adapter->query($sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($table),  $DB ::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
```

Ref [Fatal error : class not found in Zend framework 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23086956/fatal-error-class-not-found-in-zend-framework-2)

**Note:** I still fail to understand why `$this->adapter = $this->getAdapter();` not working instead of `$DB`.Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to access non existing service. You can try to create a service factory:

**config.php**

```
<?php
return [
    'db' => [
        'driver' => 'Pdo',
        'database' => 'blog',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => 'mysql'
    ]
];
```

**Module.php**

```
<?php
class Module 
{
    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return [
            'factories' => [
                'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' =>  => function ($sm) {
                     $config = $sm->get('Config');
                     return new \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter($config['db']);

                },
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Then, you can access the service with the service manager:

**AuthController.php**

```
class AuthController extends AbstractActionController 
{
    public function getAdapter()
    {
       if (!$this->adapter) {
          $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
          $this->adapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
       }
       return $this->adapter;
    }

    public function processAction()
    {
        $this->adapter = $this->getAdapter();
        $sql = new Sql($this->adapter);

        // other stuff here
    }
}
```

You can find more examples [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/tutorials/tutorial.dbadapter.html) and [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.authentication.intro.html).

Comment: Hi , I already did that on `global.php`,why we need seperate service manager for `zend\db\adapter\adapter`. Pls see my edit.

Comment: In the module.php you need the service manager in order to get the config and to inject the dependencies in the adapter constructor.

Comment: I changed this `$this->adapter->query($sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($table),  $this->adapter ::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE)`,still getting syntax error.`unidetifiend adapter`